# Evaluating limit making it $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ and using L'Hopital Rule

Tags: analysis, limits

Let $P(x)=x^n+\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}a_kx^k$. Find $$ \lim_{x \to +\infty} ([P(x)]^{1/n}-x) $$

I know that in order to solve this problem I need to multiply it by something that will make it $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ and then use L'Hopital Rule. I also know that the answer should be $1/n$ if I am not mistaken. I have tried multiplying the expression by $\frac{e^x}{e^x}$ and then using L'H. Rule but with not much success. Any suggestions on how I should proceed? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Note that asymptotically this limit tends to something like $\sqrt[n]{x^n} - x$.  If we wanted to resolve $\sqrt{x^2 + ...} - x$ then we would multiply and divide by $\sqrt{x + ...}+x$ and use the difference of squares.

So instead we would like to use something similar to difference of squares.  This leads to the equation $y^n - x^n = (y-x)(x^{n-1}y^0 + x^{n-2}y^1 + \cdots + x^{0}y^{n-1})$.  We multiply the limit top and bottom by: $(x^{n-1}y^0 + x^{n-2}y^1 + \cdots + x^{0}y^{n-1})$ taking $y=P(x)$ to reduce the numerator to $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_k x^k$.

Comment: Correction to my comment.  $y=P(x)^{1/n}$.  With a bit of algebra you could finish the problem without even appealing to l'Hospital's rule.

Comment: You should post that an answer, @Joel . In particular it interests me to see how to do this exercise without l'H.

Comment: Sure, I'll put it up when I have more time.  It's a lot like your solution, where you factor out the $x^n$ term from the radical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An idea:

$$P(x)^{1/n}-x=x\left[\left(1+\frac{a_0}{x^n}+\ldots+\frac{a_{n-1}}x\right)^{\frac1n}-1\right]=\frac{\left(1+\frac{a_0}{x^n}+\ldots+\frac{a_{n-1}}x\right)^{\frac1n}-1}{\frac1x}$$

Now you can use l'Hospital (can you see why?) and get that your limit equals

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac1n\left(-\frac{na_0}{x^{n+1}}-\ldots-\frac{a_{n-1}}{x^2}\right)\left(1+\frac{a_0}{x^n}+\ldots+\frac{a_{n-1}}x\right)^{\frac1n-1}}{-\frac1{x^2}}=$$

$$=\frac1n\;\lim_{x\to\infty}\,\left(\frac{na_0}{x^{n-1}}+\ldots+\frac{2a_{n-2}}x+a_{n-1}\right)\left(1+\frac{a_0}{x^n}+\ldots+\frac{a_{n-1}}x\right)^{\frac1n-1}=\frac{a_{n-1}}n$$

Comment: you have been faster! +1!

Comment: Hey Don, I posted my answer without l'H.  Give it a look over if you like.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way of answering this question without appealing to l'Hospital's rule.  In principle, any limit involving radicals and rational functions can be resolved by algebraic manipulations.  In fact, it's the same idea that went into the answers provided by DonAntonio and Cronus.

We wish to find the limit: $$\lim_{x\to\infty} (P(x)^{1/n} - x)$$ where $P(x) = x^n + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k x^k$ is a polynomial of degree $n$.

First we remember the polynomial equation: $$(y-x)(x^{n-1}y^0 + x^{n-2}y^1 + \cdots + x^0y^{n-1}) = y^n - x^n$$

Now take $y = P(x)^{1/n}$.  This enables us to rewrite the limit as:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}\lim_{x\to\infty} (P(x)^{1/n} - x) &=& \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{P(x) - x^n}{(x^{n-1}(P(x)^{1/n})^0 + x^{n-2}(P(x)^{1/n})^1 + \cdots + x^0(P(x)^{1/n})^{n-1})}\\
&=& \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k x^k}{(x^{n-1}(P(x)^{1/n})^0 + x^{n-2}(P(x)^{1/n})^1 + \cdots + x^0(P(x)^{1/n})^{n-1})}\end{array}$$

Now the key observation is that we can view every term in the denominator as being $x^{n-1}$ in a limiting sense:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}x^{n-k}(P(x)^{1/n})^{k-1}&=&x^{n-k}((x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdots)^{1/n})^{k-1}\\
&=&x^{n-k}(x (1 + a_{n-1} x^{-1} \cdots )^{1/n})^{k-1}\\
&=&x^{n-1}(1 + a_{n-1} x^{-1} \cdots )^{(k-1)/n}\end{array}$$

Note that $\lim_{x\to\infty} (1 + a_{n-1} x^{-1} \cdots )^{(k-1)/n} = 1$.  For convenience, note that we can write these terms as: $$x^{n-1}(P(x)/x^n)^{(k-1)/n}$$

Now let us return the the limit we are concerned with:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}\lim_{x\to\infty} (P(x)^{1/n} - x) &=& \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k x^k}{(x^{n-1}(P(x)^{1/n})^0 + x^{n-2}(P(x)^{1/n})^1 + \cdots + x^0(P(x)^{1/n})^{n-1})}\\
&=&\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k x^k}{x^{n-1}(((P(x)/x^n)^{1/n})^0 + ((P(x)/x^n)^{1/n})^1 + \cdots + ((P(x)/x^n)^{1/n})^{n-1})}\\
&=&\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} x^{-1} + \cdots + a_0 x^{-(n-1)}}{((P(x)/x^n)^{1/n})^0 + ((P(x)/x^n)^{1/n})^1 + \cdots + ((P(x)/x^n)^{1/n})^{n-1}}\end{array}$$

Finally notice this is simply a combination of limits we already know.  The numerator tends to $a_{n-1}$ as $x \to \infty$, and each of the terms in the denominator (of which there are $n$ terms) tends to 1 as we already stated.

Thus,

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} (P(x)^{1/n} - x) = \frac{a_{n-1}}{n}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$P(x)^{\frac{1}{n}} = x\Big(1 + \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}a_kx^{k-n}\Big)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$ $$P(x)^{\frac{1}{n}} - x = \frac{\Big(1 + \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}a_kx^{k-n}\Big)^{\frac{1}{n}} - 1}{\frac{1}{x}}$$ Now you can use L'Hopital rule!

Answer (score 0):

Compute the Taylor series of P(x)^(1/n)-x around x = Infinity. The result given by DonAntonio is almost immediate.