# Calculus Problem general polynomial limit to infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

I have to solve the following problem for homework for a calculus class. I really have no idea where to start, does anyone have any hints?:

let n be a positive integer greater than 0. Let P(x) be a polynomial s.t.:

$P(x) = x^n+b_1x^{n-1}+b_2x^{n-2}+...+b_{n-1}+b_n$,

Show that $lim_{x\to\infty}([P(x)]^{1/n}-x)=b_1/n$.

We're not allowed to use induction. I was thinking maybe somehow apply the pinching theorem?

Comment: You should look at this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530218/evaluating-limit-making-it-frac-infty-infty-and-using-lhopital-rule/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that for positive $x$ at which $[P(x)]^{1/n}$ is defined, we have 
$$\sqrt[n]{P(x)}=x\sqrt[n]{1+\frac{b_1}{x}+\cdots+\frac{b_n}{x^n}}.$$
Let $t=\frac{1}{x}$. We want the limit as $t$ approaches $0$ from the right of 
$$\frac{\sqrt[n]{1+b_1t +\cdots +b_n t^n}-1}{t}.\tag{1}$$
We can now use L'Hospital's Rule. Or just the definition of the derivative. Or else we can make estimates of the $n$-th root.

Or else we can rationalize the numerator. Let $u=\sqrt[n]{1+b_1t+\cdots +b_nt_n}$. Then $u-1=\frac{u^n-1}{u^{n-1}+u^{n-2}+\cdots+1}$.

Comment: You can also use the fact (if the OP knows Taylor series, for instance) that $$\sqrt[n]{1+t} = e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln(1+t)}\operatorname*{=}_{t\to 0} e^{\frac{t}{n}+o(t)} = \operatorname*{=}_{t\to 0} 1 + \frac{t}{n} + o(t).$$

Comment: Yes, the method of choice is highly dependent on the stage of the course OP is at. For the long run, the viewpoint of your comment is best.

Comment: The first equality may not be true for any positive $x.$ We only now that $\sqrt[n]{}$ exists (if $n$ is even) for $x$ large enough.

Comment: Thank you, I have added the condition that $(P(x))^{1/n}$ exists.

Comment: @mfl: Though it is not clear that one needs to. There is a convention that one can write for example $\frac{x}{x^2}=\frac{1}{x}$ since both are undefined in the same place. And I already had condition $x$ positive, and $(P(x))^{1/n}$ and $x(1+b_1/x+\cdots)^{1/n}$ are defined for the same positive $x$.